# How to translate "form-based website authentication"

Tags: информатика

Is there a canonical equivalent of "form-based website authentication" in Russian computer science?

Comment: [sighs] no, there is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Wikipedia's [OWA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OWA) article it is called "Авторизация с помощью «окна логина»". Not a notable source, but maybe better than nothing